# Javascript await/async order of execution

Tags: javascript, async-await

So I'm trying to wrap my head about promises/await/async. I can't understand why when go() is executed the alert with "finished" go right after the console.log(coffee). Why does it only wait for getCoffee() and the other axios calls are ran after the "finished" alert when all functions  are using await/promises?

```js
function getCoffee() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("☕"), 2000); // it takes 2 seconds to make coffee
  });
}
async function go() {
  try {
    alert("ok");
    const coffee = await getCoffee();

    console.log(coffee); // ☕

    const wes = await axios("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=200");
    console.log("wes"); // using string instead of value for brevity

    const wordPromise = axios("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=200");
    console.log("wordPromise"); // using string instead of value for brevity

    alert("finish");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e); // 
  }
}
go();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works as expected when I tried it (though I used node rather than a browser, and replaced alert with console logs).

Comment: @junvar I was able to reproduce the described behavior in the browser with the stack snippet above

Comment: It may be that `alert("finish")` is properly running after the axios call, but you aren't seeing `wes` in the console in time. Logging to the console is not always an instantaneous operation (whatever you log has to be processed, laid out, and painted). Essentially `console.log` can be considered an asynchronous operation that's guaranteed to run in order. Try replacing `console.log` with `alert` or `alert` with `console.log` and see if it looks right.

Comment: @stevendesu is right, I changed to all console.log and now it is processing it in the order I expected. Please place as an answer to the question and I'll accept it

Comment: @CI_Guy if you open up the developer tools when running the Stack Snippet, you'll also see the console logs are visible there when `finish` is alerted.

Comment: as @stevendesu suggested, your first promise is forcing the script to await 2 full seconds before proceeding. Then the two axios get requests and the final alert('finish') happen so fast it looks like its not waiting.

Comment: You were right thinking that the await keyword twice in a row would ensure the order of the function calls would take place as written (instead of the order being unknown due to the complexity of asyncronous coding).  @stevendesu's answer is correct that await was behaving as expected, but console.log was likely not.  Please consider accepting the edit improvement suggestions for this quest because the question can be written much more clearly than how you've provided it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `console.log` isn't always as synchronous as one might think. The specification only requires that `console.log` display a message in the developer console, but doesn't make any requirements about how or when the message will display. Depending on your browser, results may differ, however usually it's implemented something like the following:

- When you make a call to `console.log` the request gets pushed onto a <strike>stack</strike> queue (so consecutive calls to `console.log` always execute in order)
- On the next animation frame, the browser will attempt to process as much of the <strike>stack</strike> queue as possible (minimum of one element on the <strike>stack</strike> queue ***must*** be processed, so the browser may lock up if you attempt to log 8 megabytes of data)
- "Processing" the <strike>stack</strike> queue involves things like converting DOM element references to links that take you elsewhere in the dev console, converting JSON objects to navigable and collapsible UI elements, or replacing objects with the text "[Object object]"
- Once an element on the <strike>stack</strike> queue is processed, it must be rendered in the console. This requires adjusting the height of the console, determining if you need a scroll bar, determining where text will wrap, etc. This process (taking what you want in the console and actually displaying it on the screen) is called "painting"

Because `console.log` is actually a complex operation like this, it may not finish executing before the `alert` statement runs (in some browsers). By replacing every call to `alert` with `console.log` or every call to `console.log` with `alert` you should see that things are actually executing in the expected order.

Answer (score 1):

The async/await is working as intended. It is just that the the console takes some time to update or the browser is repainting, therefore the `alert` is triggered before it can repaint. You can verify it by using all `alert` instead of `console.log`. All the `alert` are executed in the correct order.As shown in the example below.

```js
function getCoffee() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {resolve("coffee")}, 2000); // it takes 2 seconds to make coffee
    });
  }
  async function go() {
    try {
      alert("ok");
      const coffee = await getCoffee();

      alert(coffee); // ☕

      const wes = await getCoffee();
      alert(wes);

      const wordPromise = getCoffee();
      alert(wordPromise);

      alert("finish");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e); // 
    }
  }
go();
```