# Javascript, async functions behave differently between Mac and Windows/Linux

Tags: javascript, macos, async-await

`await`/`async` seem to behave differently on Chrome and Safari on Mac, compared to Chrome on Windows and Linux.

```html
<select id="dbgselect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<script>
    async function dbg(type) {
        console.log(`A [${type}]`);
        await dbg2(type);
        console.log(`B [${type}]`);
    }
    
    async function dbg2(type) {
        console.log(`C [${type}]`);
    }
    
    document.getElementById("dbgselect").oninput = () => { dbg("input"); };
    document.getElementById("dbgselect").onchange = () => { dbg("change"); };
</script>
```

When making a selection in the dropdown, the output on Linux/Windows (on Chrome) is:

```
A [input]
C [input]
A [change]
C [change]
B [input]
B [change]
```

The output on Mac (on both Chrome and Safari):

```
A [input]
C [input]
B [input]
A [change]
C [change]
B [change]
```

HOWEVER - if I add this at the bottom, to invoke `dbg` outside the context of an event:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    dbg("input");
    dbg("change");
}, 0);
```

Then the result on Mac **changes**, and becomes the same as on Linux and Windows (i.e. `A,C,A,C,B,B` instead of `A,C,B,A,C,B`).

My questions:

1. Is either of these implementations a bug? (i.e. a violation of some standard).
2. Is this difference in behavior documented or discussed anywhere? I couldn't find.

Comment: Are these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153537/javascript-await-async-order-of-execution & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235606/asynchronous-javascript-execution-order

Comment: `setTimeout(() => dbg('input'), 0); setTimeout(() => dbg('change'), 0);` would be the relevant one, for two events at the same time. Looks like on windows the "two" events are just one. However, i am not versed enough in the html spec to know, so time to wait for a html guru :)

Comment: @vee thanks, but not really. I don't want to over-complicate the question with additional code, but i verified that it's not related to difference in console.log behavior (i changed console.log to arr.push() and then printed it to console when all is done).

Comment: @ASDFGerte it seems that both events are actually handled in the same tick, in both Linux and Mac. i tested this by adding `setInterval(() => { cnt++; }, 0)`, and then logging `cnt` in the console.log lines. the `cnt` counter value is the same for both events, on both systems.

Comment: I don't think that you can test it that way. `setInterval` isn't accurate below 4-6ms, and all you notice is, that both event handlers were fired, not, whether they were listed as separate events or not.

Comment: @ASDFGerte please also notice that my results show that with the `setTimeout()` approach, the Mac behavior actually becomes **asynchronous**, despite the two `dbg()` calls being made synchronously one after the other.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, ok, I also tested with `setTimeout(.., 0)`. is that reliable? if not, then how can i check if both events are fired in the same JS tick or not?

Comment: I think we are flooding comments - are you familiar with the difference between microtask- and eventqueue? Resolved promise's callbacks are evaluated before any further events, meaning if there are two, mac's behavior is the correct one. You can see this with the two sequential `setTimeout` i posted above, creating two timer events, which fire at the same time.

Comment: You're right, using two `setTimeout` gives the same result as Mac's event handling. I am not familiar with microtask or eventqueue. Maybe the difference lies not in the `async` implementation, but in (the timing of) how the events are fired. I also find it curious that the behavior is consistent between Chrome and Safari on Mac, but inconsistent between Chrome on Mac and Chrome on Linux/Windows...